# How to remove default cart icon image in header from my custom theme?

Tags: magento2, image, mini-cart

I have developed custom theme, and added own cart icon image using

app\design\frontend\Mytheme\theme\web\css\source_extend.less

```
.minicart-wrapper .showcart::before {
    // content: "" !important;
    background: url('../images/cart.png') no-repeat;
    width: 27px;
    height: 25px;
    padding-left: 37px !important;
  }
```

But default cart icon image also shown, how to remove default one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart:before{
    content:"";
    background-image: url('../images/cart.png') no-repeat;
    width: 27px;
    height: 25px;
    padding-left: 37px;
}
```

**Add the above css after run the below commnds,**

```
bin/magento s:up
bin/magento s:s:d -f
bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: Did you missed Semicolon
 or?

Comment: yes , now updated please check.

Comment: The default cart icon remove from web view ( styles-l.css ) how to remove same from mobile view ( styles-m.css )

Comment: Screenshot: https://snipboard.io/6jHAhr.jpg